# how to feed command output to current shell

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

[linux, bash-4.1.2]
I'm writing a bash script to:

1) set up some shell variables and shell functions

2) extract a portion of another script with sed

3) run the extract in the current shell, using the stuff I set up.

I have it working with:

```
sed -n -e /aaa/,/kkk/p >tmpfile
. ./tmpfile
```

but it seems there should be a simpler way to redirect the output of the sed to the current shell, without using a temp file.  Any ideas?  Is there some exotic redirection that will do this?

The script extract has lots of here docs and shell var expansions, so a simple eval does not work at all.  Here's a much simplified example:

```
function Test(){ testnum=$2; echo $*; } 
Test 1_69 has 1M ross
src=src${testnum}
vsql -Xa <<EOF
drop table $src cascade;
EOF
ddlfile=${TMPDIR}.$src.sql.ddl
make_wide_table --table_name=$src --rows 1 --unsegmented > $ddlfile
vsql -X -f $ddlfile
vsql -X <<EOF
select * from $src;
select refresh('$src');
EOF
for ip in {0001..0010}; do 
    vsql-c "create projection ${src}p${ip} as select * from $src"
done
```

The bash doc says "eval: The arguments are concatenated together into a single command...".

Comment: `eval $(sed -n -e /aaa/,/kkk/p)`

Comment: eval doesn't work for a long script full of here-doc's, function definitions, and variable expansions  and such.

Comment: In that case, your solution is probably the best solution.